# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getEditor' of undefined in .Net 4.5

Tags: asp.net

My aspx page just shows a blank textarea without the toolbar.

This is the error in the Console.Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getEditor' of undefined in .Net 4.5

This is the code

```
<textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80" placeholder="Property Description" ValidationGroup="ins" MaxLength="10000" runat="server"> </textarea>
```

Any help?

Comment: Are you using CKEditor (`getEditor()` function is originated from that library)? Please provide [mcve] to your current issue too (you're just providing the markup, important JS code is not included).